# How to get AM/PM by ADDTIME() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have one field `startTime` in my database and the value is `'7:00:00 PM'`, I want to add 20 minutes in this time and store this in a new field as `endtime`. I want `endtime` in same format as is `startTime` that is '07:20:00 PM', I used `ADDTIME`, and many more function to do this, but unable to get the format of `AM/PM`, I used

```
DATE_ADD('NEXT_CONTACT_TIME', INTERVAL 20 MINUTE), DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(NEXT_CONTACT_TIME,'00:20:00'),'%h:%i:%s %p') as endTime
```

But, I'm not able to get `AM`/`Pm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This

```
DECLARE @StartTime TIME(0) = '07:00:00 AM'; --Time
DECLARE @MinutesToAdd INT = 20; --Added 20 Minutes
SELECT SUBSTRING((CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(MINUTE, @MinutesToAdd, @StartTime), 109)),0,8) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), DATEADD(MINUTE, @MinutesToAdd, @StartTime), 9), 2) as Time
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge mysql default time format is 24HR that means there is no am/pm you should manage the time  when fetching or after fetching the data.

> A date and time combination. The supported range is '1000-01-01
>   00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'. MySQL displays DATETIME values in
>   'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format, but permits assignment of values to
>   DATETIME columns using either strings or numbers.

Refer [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html)